# Remove numbering in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

When I load images into ListView, the numbers appear below the images. How can I remove them?
The following is my code to load images into ListView:

```
    DataTable dtPath = new DataTable();
        dtPath = ContrPtMRD.SelectFilePaths(ObjPtMRH);
        ImageList myImageList = new ImageList();
        lvPtMedicalRecord.LargeImageList = myImageList;
        int imageIndex = 0;
        foreach (DataRow rows in dtPath.Rows)
        {
            myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(rows[2].ToString()));
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[]{rows[0].ToString(),rows[1].ToString()});
            lvi.ImageIndex = imageIndex; 
            imageIndex++;
            lvPtMedicalRecord.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

Comment: what does `rows[0].ToString()` consist of? where are the numbers coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView will not add any image numbers unless you explicitly add them. You are doing so in the following line:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[]{rows[0].ToString(),rows[1].ToString()});
```

and the number seem to be coming from

```
rows[0].ToString()
```

Which is the text property of the ListViewItem.
To remove the numbers, replace

```
 rows[0].ToString()
```

with an empty string or use one of the ListViewItem's constructors that does not require you to provide the text property:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear where are the numbers coming from but I think the numbers are in the first column of your `DataTable`. If you want to remove the numbers then dont add the first column values to your `ListView` as Items.

**or else**

Hide the column in the ListView which you dont want to show.

**or else**

Change the view of the `ListView` to large details.(this will not show the `item` value, only `subItems` will be visible)